# What are the basic next steps to tropicalize a curve of degree $6$ (ideally using any CAS)?

Tags: curves, algebraic-curves, combinatorial-geometry, tropical-geometry

First of all, I must admit that the topic of Tropicalization is new to me. I have a rough outline and I'm by no means asking for a ready-made solution here, but rather some pointers on how to get an initial visualization most straight-forwardly. Solution hints that require tools (or a combination of them) like Mathematica, Matlab, Maple are absolutely no problem - in fact, they are very welcome.

I have the following curve of degree six:

$$0=16y^6+48x^2y^4-20y^4+48x^4y^2-40x^2y^2+5y^2+16x^6-20x^4+5x^2-x$$

The curve is plotted by the following figure (red curve):

[image]

The blue curve is of degree eight and hopefully (based on the computational pilot for the red curve) I can then transfer the approach to the blue curve by my own.

What I understood so far is that I have to extract the coefficients of all monomials $(i,j)$ for $x^iy^j$ of our curve.

Since our curve is of degree $6$, we have $36$ coefficients, namely for monomials given by $(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (5, 0), (5, 1), (6, 0)$

These coefficients then are:
$(0, 0, 5, 0, -20, 0, 16, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, -40, 0, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -20, 0, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0)$

Then I divided these coefficients by $48$ (the largest one) to obtain "normalized" coefficients that lie within the intervall $[-1,1]$:
$(0, 0, 0.104166666, 0, -0.4166666, 0, 0.33333, 0, -0.020833333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.104166666, 0.0, -0.833333, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.4166666, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.33333, 0, 0)$

How can I obtain most straight-forwardly a tropicalization visualized? Sketching the next steps would help me a lot finishing my task.

*To complete the big picture, I am adding more background information:*

The blue curve has the equation:

$$0=-64y^8-256x^2y^6+112y^6-384x^4y^4+336x^2y^4-56y^4-256x^6y^2+336x^4y^2-112x^2y^2+7y^2-64x^8+112x^6-56x^4+7x^2+x$$

Both curves can be formulated by a parameter form.
The red curve within the domain $\frac{4\pi}{3}<t<2\pi$:

\begin{array}{l}
x^2+y^2=y\sin t+x\cos t\\
x^2+y^2=y\sin\frac{3t}{2}+x\cos\frac{3t}{2}
\end{array}

and the blue curve within its domain $0<t<\frac{4\pi}{3}$:

\begin{array}{l}
x^2+y^2=y\sin t+x\cos t\\
x^2+y^2=-y\sin\frac{3t}{4}-x\cos\frac{3t}{4}
\end{array}

It would intersting to know, whether we can restrict the tropicalization to these domains.

Comment: If I've used it correctly, tropical.lib in Singular gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvJn6.png).

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. This is the direction I would like to go. It would be great if you may describe this including some intermediate steps tying to the given ones (in the question). I would love to retrace what is the complete (computational) walk for such tropicalizations. I would like to implement a step by step solution in Mathematica, Matlab or Maple...

Comment: On osx I got Singular from brew, and downloaded [http://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/~keilen/download/Tropical/polymake.lib](http://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/~keilen/download/Tropical/polymake.lib) and put it in the directory I run Singular from, making sure that it's a .lib extension, not a .txt. Then 
`LIB "tropical.lib";`
`ring r=(0,t),(x,y),dp;`
`poly 16*y^6+48*x^2*y^4-20*y^4+48*x^4*y^2-40*x^2*y^2+5*y^2+16*x^6-20*x^4+5*x^2-x;`
`drawTropicalCurve(f,"max");`

produces a postscript file, that I ps2pdf'd and took a screenshot of.

What worries me is that the parameter, $t,$ is not used.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I'll try to play around with your approach (using my Windows environment). Agree - it is strange that the parameter $t$ is ommitted. What I additionally found is this solution from Wolfram: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TropicalCurves/. Unfortunatelly it just uses random parameters instead of giving the possibility to enter concrete polynomials.

Comment: I got Singular up and running. The Lib tropical.lib is also present. But when typing the command `poly 16*y^6+48*x^2*y^4-20*y^4+48*x^4*y^2-40*x^2*y^2+5*y^2+16*x^6-20*x^4+5*x^2-x;` I get the error: `error occurred in or before STDIN line 3: 'ly 16*y^6+48*x^2*y^4-20*y^4+48*x^4*y^2-40*x^2*y^2+5*y^2+16*x^6-20*x^4+5*x^2-x;' wrong type declaration. type 'help poly;' last reserved name was 'poly' error at token ';'`

Comment: Sorry, I dropped a `f=`. Also you need latex installed.

Comment: Great - after some cygwin package installations I finally got it working and obtain the same result as you provided. Your approach is very straight-forward. Now I can try various polynomials (and possibly recode this in Mathematica or Python). Thank you again!