# How do I interpret the tropicalized curves (one of degree $6$ and one of degree $8$)?

Tags: curves, algebraic-curves, combinatorial-geometry, tropical-geometry

For me, the topic of tropicalization is new and I am trying to understand what new insights and perspectives tropicalization could provide me on the following two curves (degree 6 and 8). So it is a pure experiment without knowing what can come out of it. Both curves construct a "heartshape" (see [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Dqy.png)), about which I would like to learn experimentally what information tropicalization can contribute to me.

With the kind help of Jan-Magnus Økland (see [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4254541/what-are-the-basic-next-steps-to-tropicalize-a-curve-of-degree-6-ideally-usin)) I could computationally tropicalize two curves:

- $\color{red}{\textbf{Red:}}$ $0=16y^6+48x^2y^4-20y^4+48x^4y^2-40x^2y^2+5y^2+16x^6-20x^4+5x^2-x$ (curve of degree)
- $\color{blue}{\textbf{Blue:}}$ $0=-64y^8-256x^2y^6+112y^6-384x^4y^4+336x^2y^4-56y^4-256x^6y^2+336x^4y^2-112x^2y^2+7y^2-64x^8+112x^6-56x^4+7x^2+x$ (curve of degree 8)

Now I am trying to interpret the result of this tropicalization, e.g. how do I "read" these tropical curves? For this I watched the video ["What is tropical geometry?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYqGanjjUdQ&t=335s), but it is still for me not very clear how to comprehend that principle in the context of my concrete case. I would be grateful for any directions and hints to interpret the tropicalization result.

[image]

For those who are interested - I used the following Singular code for the tropicalization:

```
LIB "tropical.lib";
ring r=(0,t),(x,y),dp;
poly f=16*y^6+48*x^2*y^4-20*y^4+48*x^4*y^2-40*x^2*y^2+5*y^2+16*x^6-20*x^4+5*x^2-x;
poly f=-64*y^8-256*x^2*y^6+112*y^6-384*x^4*y^4+336*x^2*y^4-56*y^4-256*x^6*y^2+336*x^4*y^2-112*x^2*y^2+7*y^2-64*x^8+112*x^6-56*x^4+7*x^2+x;
drawTropicalCurve(f,"max");
```

Comment: Why those two particular curves, and why not start with something simpler such as degree 2 and degree 3? Have you tried that first?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, these two curves are important for me (subject of investigation). I implicitized them from the original parametric form $x^2+y^2=y\sin t+x\cos t$, $x^2+y^2=y\sin\frac{3t}{2}+x\cos\frac{3t}{2}$ (red curve) and $x^2+y^2=y\sin t+x\cos t$, $x^2+y^2=-y\sin\frac{3t}{4}-x\cos\frac{3t}{4}$ (blue curve).

Comment: Again, I am confused. What would you do with the tropicalization of the two curves? What important infromation would it give you that you can use to solve your problem? In other words, what is your real problem and how would tropicalization help you to solve it?

Comment: I try to give my best to describe the problem behind the two original curves. The curve that draws a heartshape (see the original linked MSE post) is created as follows: We use the unit circle with the vertices that are labeled as show by this figure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhMz1.png. We connect a vertex $P_1=(\cos t,\sin t)$ labeled by $x$ with a vertex $P_2$ labeled by $3x$. Both vertices $P_1$ and $P_2$ lie on the unit circle and the line connecting them is a tangent of this heartshape drawing envelope.

Comment: Please let me know if can give more information. I try to do the tropicalization in an exploratory manner with the hope to become another perspective on these curves. Hence, it is an experiment to get a new view on that envelope.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not effectively answered any of my questions so far. That is not a good sign.

Comment: My real problem is to explore the heartshape that is build by the red and blue curve pieces: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4254541/what-are-the-basic-next-steps-to-tropicalize-a-curve-of-degree-6-ideally-usin. and I try exploratively to get a new view on this curve. I am trying to answer the question "what information or new insights can a tropicalization give me?" It is really an experiment without knowing exactly what will come out. I'm trying to get a new view on the heartshape. Do you need more information on how I obtained the heartshape?